# android user login using php and oracle database 10g

Tags: php, android, oracle

I'm developing an android application and I'm having trouble with my user login using PHP and oracle 10g. I can't find any examples working with oracle.

This is my php code :

```
include("connexion.php");

if (!empty($_POST)) {

if (empty($_POST['code_client']) || empty($_POST['password_client'])) { 

 $response["success"] = 0; 
 $response["message"] = "One or both of the fields are empty ."; 


die(json_encode($response)); } 

$query = " SELECT * FROM client_mb WHERE code_client = '$code_client'and password_client='$password_client'"; 

$result = oci_parse($connect, $query);

oci_execute($result); 

$row = oci_fetch_array($result);

if (!empty($row)) { 

$response["success"] = 1;

 $response["message"] = "You have been sucessfully login";

die(json_encode($response)); } 

 else{ 

 $response["success"] = 0; 

 $response["message"] = "invalid username or password "; 

 die(json_encode($response)); 
 } 

 } else{ 

 $response["success"] = 0;

 $response["message"] = " One or both of the fields are empty "; 


die(json_encode($response)); 

 } 
  include("deconnexion.php");
```

This is my java code :

```
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";

private static final String TAG_MESSAGE = "message";

public static final String TAG_CODE = "code_client";

public static final String TAG_PWD = "password_client";


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    txtcode = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.login);
    txtpass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.mdp);

    bLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
    bLogin.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {


        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            cde = txtcode.getText().toString();
            password = txtpass.getText().toString();

            if ((TextUtils.isEmpty(cde)) || (TextUtils.isEmpty(password))) {
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,
                        "Veuillez remplir tous les champs",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            else {

                new AttemptLogin().execute(LOGIN_URL);




            }

        }

    });

}

class AttemptLogin extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {


 @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(LoginActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub // here Check for success tag
        int success;

        try {

            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_CODE, cde));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_PWD, password));
            Log.d("request!", "starting");

            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(LOGIN_URL, "GET",
                    params);


            Log.d("Login attempt", json.toString());
            success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
            if (success == 1) {

                Log.d("Successfully Login!", json.toString());
                Intent i = new Intent(LoginActivity.this,
                        MenuEspaceClientActivity.class);

                finish();

                startActivity(i);
                return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
            } else {
                return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }


    protected void onPostExecute(String message) {
        pDialog.dismiss();

        if (message != null) {
            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
        }


    }
}
```

I'm working with JSONParser class. Is there something wrong with my code? I can't figure out what's wrong. Is there a working example that I can maybe use?

Edit: I have the following in my Android logcat:

> Skipped 140 frames! The application may be doing too much work on its main thread. Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@1ee6a42c attribute=null, token = android.os.BinderProxy@3ed2ccef couldn't log to binary event log: overflow. Excessive delay setting light: 195ms User[0] Flushing usage stats to disk

Comment: You did post your code, but what are the errors you are getting?

Comment: 04-19 17:50:36.743: D/Login attempt(2023): {"success":0,"message":" One or both of the fields are empty "}

Comment: Did you call  `oci_connect()` and try to print errors after each call by calling `oci_error()`

Comment: @Tarun yes I have a php file in wich i have the following code:                 <?php
$connect  = ocilogon(db,pas,"127.0.0.1/xe");
 ?>     How do I use oci_error ?

Comment: Check this [link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.oci-error.php)

Comment: @Tarun When i used it i got this error : A resource was acquired at attached stack trace but never released. See java.io.Closeable for information on avoiding resource leaks.

Comment: Are you shutting down the http connection after making the request?

Comment: Yes at the end of the php file I call oci_close($connect);

Comment: Why You don't use gson for that?
I think gson with retrofit will be best choice for such REST-like php service.

Comment: @udenfox how do i use gson ?

Comment: @yasmine try look at that post, it may be helpful http://blog.robinchutaux.com/blog/a-smart-way-to-use-retrofit/

Comment: Are the values of `$code_client` and `$password_client` actually set? They do not appear to be. Security issues: it looks like you may have a SQL injection vulnerability here. You should also hash your passwords, and not store them in plain text.

Comment: @halfer can you please tell me how do i find out if i have an SQL injection vulnerability, and if i do , how do i fix it ?

Comment: The `$query` may have the SQL injection issue. To fix, [read this](https://php.net/manual/en/function.oci-bind-by-name.php).

Comment: @halfer thanks for your help ! I tried adding oci_bind_by_name but it's still not working :(

Comment: There is a couple of issues I'd raise here. First, if you amend your code, please also amend the copy in the question, otherwise we can't see what you are looking at. Also, please never use the phrase "it doesn't work" - we often say here that it is the least helpful fault report possible. Instead, say what did happen, and what you wanted to happen. Include any error messages (you may need to look into logs for these). As it stands, I don't think anyone can tell you why your parameter binding is not working.

Comment: @halfer what i meant to say by "it doesn't work" that it's not showing me the right result , I get the message "one or both fields are empty" and this is what my logcat looks like:

Comment: Skipped 140 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@1ee6a42c attribute=null, token = android.os.BinderProxy@3ed2ccef
couldn't log to binary event log: overflow.
Excessive delay setting light: 195ms
User[0] Flushing usage stats to disk

Comment: Ah, you need to fix that first - [it happens a lot](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=%20The%20application%20may%20be%20doing%20too%20much%20work%20on%20its%20main%20thread) (1,233 search results at the time of writing).

Comment: (If you would update the above code with your parameter binding, that would be good. I'll undownvote if you do so, since I've already asked for this).

Comment: Here it is ! I just changed this section of the code : $query = " SELECT * FROM client_mb WHERE code_client = :code_client and password_client = :password_client "; 
 $result = oci_parse($connect, $query);
  oci_bind_by_name($result, ":code_client", $code_client);
   oci_bind_by_name($result, ":password_client", $password_client);
 oci_execute($result, OCI_DEFAULT);

Comment: ^ OK. Would you [edit it into the question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/29734271/edit)?

Comment: You posted an error _A resource was acquired at attached stack trace but never released. See java.io.Closeable for information on avoiding resource leaks._ Did you see this in android logcat or php? My reply was to close the http connection in your android code.

Comment: As @udenfox rightly pointed out. Use retrofit or volley for consuming rest apis.

Comment: I've voted to put on hold, as the question is either a duplicate (see my search link) or not reproducible given the information in the question.

Comment: @Tarun that was in my logcat

Comment: Again better approach would be to use library like Retrofit. The reason you are seeing that in the logcat is your http connection is not closed.

Comment: Check if the connection is closed in `makeHttpRequest` after you process the request. The close call should be added in `finally` block.

Comment: okay thnks for the help everyone !

Comment: Did you solve the issue and how?

Comment: Yes I solved the problem . I removed the first if (in my php code) and added this instead : $code_client = $_POST["code_client "]; 
$password_client = $_POST["password_client "];

Comment: That makes sense.. You are indeed making a 'GET' request and everyone missed that too.

Comment: I'm kinda confused about that .I still don't quiet get why it's a post request and not get . I know that get is for select and reading data and post for inserting and modifying data.

Comment: `jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(LOGIN_URL, "GET",params);` You are passing GET and I assume makeHttpRequest is making GET request.

Comment: Once I changed it to POST and changed my php code , the problem was solved

Comment: Glad to hear that and move to a better solution provided by retrofit.

Answer (score 0):

In your method makeHttprequest() you are asking for a get request but in your php script you are checking it in a post request.